# C# / ASP.NET / AD - "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist."

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

When submitting valid credentials to Active Directory via a ASP.NET web form, the following error message is returned: "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist."

Code for LDAP Authentication:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace FormsAuth
{
    public class LdapAuthentication
    {
        private string _path;
        private string _filterAttribute;

        public LdapAuthentication(string path)
        {
            _path = path;
        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd)
        {
            string domainAndUsername = "CBHC" + @"\" + username;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

            try
            {
                //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
                object obj = entry.NativeObject;

                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

                if (null == result)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
                _path = result.Path;
                _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
            }

            return true;
        }

        public string GetGroups()
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
            search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
            StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
                string dn;
                int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

                for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount; propertyCounter++)
                {
                    dn = (string)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];
                    equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                    commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                    if (-1 == equalsIndex)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                    groupNames.Append("|");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. " + ex.Message);
            }
            return groupNames.ToString();
        }
    } 
}
```

Code on login page:

```
<script runat=server>
void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string adPath = "LDAP://server/DC=domain,DC=loc"; //Path to your LDAP directory server
  LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
  try
  {
    if(true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated("CBHC",txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
      string groups = adAuth.GetGroups();

      //Create the ticket, and add the groups.
      bool isCookiePersistent = chkPersist.Checked;
      FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
                txtUsername.Text,DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups);

      //Encrypt the ticket.
      string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

      //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
      HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

      if(true == isCookiePersistent)
      authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

      //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
      Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

      //You can redirect now.

      Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text, false));
    }
    else
    {
      errorLabel.Text = "Authentication did not succeed. Check user name and password.";
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    errorLabel.Text = "Error authenticating. " + ex.Message;
  }
}
</script>
```

Authentication settings on Web.config for form on IIS:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
```

Word of note: This does not occur when running the site in Debug; in that situation, it authenticates perfectly and moves on to the Default page. It only occurs when contacting the page live on the IIS server.

Comment: Have you run the code through the debugger to determine the exact line that is giving you the error.

Comment: Does the domain have the same name ?  When you try to run the site on the server machine with localhost, what error do you get ?

Comment: Che: It authenticates with no problem on the IIS server using localhost.

Answer (score 3):

I've hit an issue like this once. It may be because you can't retrieve LDAP `NativeObject` property for authentication. If the exception is thrown right after the `object obj = entry.NativeObject;` call, check if user has permissions on the domain.

Either debug through your code to see if it is indeed the NativeObject binding that is failing. Or Put a try/catch block around the binding in your IsAuthenticated() function like below. You should see the custom error thrown if it's caused by the issue I'm describing.

```
try
{   //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.         
    Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCode == -2147016694) // -2147016694 - The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.
    {
        throw new Exception("Can't retrieve LDAP NativeObject property");
    }
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Sadly I don’t think this applies to us… We only have one domain and are not trying to authenticate across multiple.

Comment: Not sure how you came to the conclusion that I'm talking about multiple domains. What I mean to say is that, if the user you are trying to authenticate does not have read access to the Active Directory Domain, then you will get the exception: -2147016694 The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

Comment: Sorry. Asked somebody else to interpret your previous answer as my AD knowledge is minimal and I am not a domain admin.

This user (me) is able to access other AD-authenticated servers / programs / etc. on the domain.

Comment: Yes. It returns that error code.

Comment: I noticed that you have <authentication mode="Windows">. You should use <authentication mode="Forms">. Also follow the instructions in the "To configure IIS for anonymous authentication" section in the following [Active Directory Authentication from ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, TonyV. Gave that a go. No luck.